# Can we execute az containerapp commands whenever a replica has been scaled up in an Azure container app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-container-apps, azure-monitor

I want to execute a script (which is present inside the container) whenever a container replica has been scaled up.

For initial deployment, we can use `az container exec` to execute the shell script. How to handle this?

Note: I don't want to use this as a entry point of my container.

I'm having naive thought process of relying on some trigger with Azure functions or logic apps. Is there any better solution?

Comment: One solution to execute a script inside a container whenever a replica has been scaled up is to use Azure Event Grid. You can create an event subscription for the Azure Container Apps resource provider and specify the event type as "Microsoft.ContainerApps/replicaScaleUp/action". Then, you can create an Azure Function or Logic App that listens to this event and executes the desired script inside the container using the az container exec command.

Comment: Another option is to use Kubernetes events. Azure Container Apps is built on top of Kubernetes, so you can create a Kubernetes event trigger that listens for the "ScaledUp" event and executes the script using the kubectl exec command.

Both of these solutions require some setup and configuration, but they provide a more scalable and flexible way to execute scripts inside containers based on events.

Comment: References:

-   [Set scaling rules in Azure Container Apps (azure-cli)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/scale-app?pivots=azure-cli#considerations)
-   [Deploying and scaling an ASP.NET Core app on Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/scaling-aspnet-apps/scaling-aspnet-apps?view=aspnetcore-8.0#deploying-and-scaling-an-aspnet-core-app-on-azure-container-apps)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [init containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/containers#init-containers). Those will run before your main container.